# Как правильно сделать цикл для записи элементов в exel?

Tags: javascript, циклы, sheetjs

```
const resul = [
  { title: 'площадка Smart', elements: ['ru.testapp', 'tv.mob.ios.tests'] },
  { title: 'площадка iOS', elements: ['ru.testapp', 'mob_tests_ios'] }
];
```

Каким образом написать цикл для сохранения в файл exel используя библиотеку sheet js, чтобы элементы сохранялись в столбец слева, а заголовки справа от них один раз для каждой группы элементов?
При этом цикл проходит три раза, необходимо исключить задваивание. Нужен только цикл.
Должно получиться так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сейчас используется следующий код:

```
data.value.bundles.forEach(bundle => {
  bundle.elements.forEach(element => {
    const existingPair = wsElements.find(([elem, title]) => elem === element && title === bundle.title);
    if (!existingPair) {
      wsElements.push([element, bundle.title]);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Покажите, какой цикл вы используете сейчас

Comment: Cайчас использую forEach, но заголовки сохраняются для каждого элемента; data.value.bundles.forEach(bundle => {
bundle.elements.forEach(element => {
                    const existingPair = wsElements.find(([elem, title]) => elem === element && title === bundle.title);
                    if (!existingPair) {
                        wsElements.push([element, bundle.title]);
                    }
                });
            });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как один из вариантов, это добавлять пустую строку для "не первых" элементов массива elements

```
data.value.bundles.forEach(bundle => {
  bundle.elements.forEach((element, index) => { // Добавили индекс
    const existingPair = wsElements.find(([elem, title]) => elem === element && title === bundle.title);
    if (!existingPair) {
      wsElements.push([element, index ? '' : bundle.title]); // Если 0, то заголовок, иначе пусто
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, помогло!