# Создание объекта из эксель таблицы через exceljs

Tags: javascript, node.js

подскажите пожалуйста как можно реализовать заполнение массива с объектами из таблицы.
Скрин как выглядит таблица:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На выходе должен получить массив с объектами такого вида

```
[{number: 1, subdivision: 'Подразделение1', arrJob: [{job: 'Должность1' num: 2}, {job: 'Должность2' num: 1}]}, 
{number: 2, subdivision: 'Подразделение2', arrJob: [{job: 'Должность1' num: 2}, {job: 'Должность2' num: 1}]}]
```

Не могу понять как правильно добавить добавить данные столбцов C и D внутрь созданного объекта. В этих столбцах для каждого подразделения будет разное количество данных.

```
const workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
workbook.getWorksheet();
workbook.xlsx
  .readFile('Базовая таблица.xlsx')
  .then(() => {
    const worksheet = workbook.getWorksheet(1);
    const arr = [];
    const { lastRow } = worksheet;

    const cell = (lit, num) => worksheet.getCell(lit + num);

    for (let startRow = 2; startRow <= lastRow.number; startRow += 1) {
      const obj = { arrJob: [] };
      if (cell('A', startRow).value) {
        obj.number = cell('A', startRow).value;
        obj.subdivision= cell('B', startRow).value;
        arr.push(obj);
      }
    }
    console.log(arr);
  })
```

Comment: [Прям очень похожий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1562789/)

Comment: спасибо за ответ, уже сам успел придумать решение, при отсутствие значения в столбце А получать последний элемент массива и добавлять в него данные